# Illegal to leave child younger than 14 alone in Illinois?

Tags: family-law, illinois

I saw [in an article a list](http://www.latchkey-kids.com/latchkey-kids-age-limits.htm) that implied that in Illinois it is illegal for parents to leave any of their children unsupervised at any time by an adult if the child is under 14 years of age.

Is this true?

Comment: A quick search is showing that the under 14 years of age thing is if the child is left unsupervised for an "unreasonable" amount of time. I saw another link that says, for example, an 11 year old shouldn't be left alone or supervising other children for longer than 3 hours. No time to research further.

Answer (score 2):

The claim is probably based on this language from the Illinois Statutes:

> § 2-3.  Neglected or abused minor.
>
> (1) Those who are neglected include:
>
> [...]
>
> (d) any minor under the age of 14 years whose parent or other person
> responsible for the minor's welfare leaves the minor without
> supervision for an unreasonable period of time without regard for the
> mental or physical health, safety, or welfare of that minor;

[Illinois Statutes Chapter 705. Courts § 405/2-3. Neglected or abused minor](http://codes.findlaw.com/il/chapter-705-courts/il-st-sect-705-405-2-3.html)

So no, it is not always illegal to leave a child under 14 unsupervised; however, it is illegal (or at least considered neglect) if the child is unsupervised "for an unreasonable period of time".

What that means in practice probably depends on the interpretation of courts and child protection agencies...